# Check if a table exists using EF Core 2.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework the existence of a table can be checked this way:

```
bool exists = context.Database
                 .SqlQuery<int?>(@"
                     SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables AS T
                     INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id
                     WHERE S.Name = 'SchemaName' AND T.Name = 'TableName'")
                 .SingleOrDefault() != null;
```

I am using **EF Core 2.1** and the method `SqlQuery` does not exist.

What would be the right way of checking whether or not a table exists? Ideally without trying to access the table and assuming it doesn't exist if an exception is thrown.

**EDIT: My final implementation**

```
public bool TableExists(string tableName)
{
    return TableExists("dbo", tableName);
}

public bool TableExists(string schema, string tableName)
{
    var connection = Context.Database.GetDbConnection();

    if (connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
        connection.Open();

    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = @"
            SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema
            AND TABLE_NAME = @TableName";

        var schemaParam = command.CreateParameter();
        schemaParam.ParameterName = "@Schema";
        schemaParam.Value = schema;
        command.Parameters.Add(schemaParam);

        var tableNameParam = command.CreateParameter();
        tableNameParam.ParameterName = "@TableName";
        tableNameParam.Value = tableName;
        command.Parameters.Add(tableNameParam);

        return command.ExecuteScalar() != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you expand on `is not valid`?

Comment: have you tried `FromSql`?

Comment: Is the question about an “open query” in general, or strictly a table existence check?

Comment: @JohnB The method doesn't exist in EF Core.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [`ExecuteSqlCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlcommand?view=efcore-2.1).

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("...")
```

However, it's limited to returning an integer indicating how many rows were affected. No rows get affected if you're doing a `SELECT`, so it doesn't really work for what you want.

There is also [`FromSql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsql?view=efcore-2.1), but that only works on tables, not at the database level:

```
context.TableName.FromSql("SELECT ...")
```

For what you're doing, a better option is to get the `DbConnection` from EF, and create your own `DbCommand`. This returns what you would expect:

```
var conn = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
if (conn.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed)) await conn.OpenAsync();
using (var command = conn.CreateCommand()) {
    command.CommandText = @"
    SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables AS T
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id
    WHERE S.Name = 'SchemaName' AND T.Name = 'TableName'";
    var exists = await command.ExecuteScalarAsync() != null;
}
```

A word of warning here: Don't put the `DbConnection` you get from `GetDbConnection()` in a `using` statement, or close it when you're done. That connection is used for the life of that `DbContext` instance. So if you close it, any later requests made by EF will fail. It's also possible that it was already opened before your code, which is why I put a test in there to see if it's closed before calling `OpenAsync()`.

Comment: How can I check if the table exists using FromSql? As far as I know it needs an entity to map to, so would I need to build a Dto for Information Schema?

Comment: You need to know the table already to use `FromSql`, so I don't think you can use it to determine if a table exists.

Comment: Now that I'm back in the office, I could do some testing. I found another way. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, I've also edited my question with my final implementation.

Comment: Nit: Closing the connection is Okay (it will be re-opened), Disposing the connection (as per using) is not, as future Open calls will fail.. in fact, ensuring the connection is Closed might be "better" to return the connection back to the pool immediately.